# Calculus book for computer science students

Tags: calculus, reference-request, computer-science, book-recommendation, online-resources

I'm going to teach calculus I and II to undergraduate computer science students and I would like to know if someone here knows some book or site with *easy* calculus applications in computer science.

Thanks

Comment: I would love to see something like this for Linear Algebra. One where computer science or programming is used as a backbone to learn linear algebra. That would be awesome!

Answer (score 2):

I ended up on your question because I had the same. The only textbook I found with some programs is this:

http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780857294456

Answer (score 0):

["Calculus" by Thomas Finney](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Calculus-Analytic-Geometry-George/dp/0201712164/ref=sr_1_12?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1451676832&sr=1-12&keywords=calculus+finney). Its very accessible and written in a practical calculus kind of way, this should suit your engineering background.

Otherwise, try [Schaum's Outline of Calculus](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Schaums-Outline-Calculus-6th-Edition/dp/0071795537/ref=pd_sim_14_2?ie=UTF8&dpID=51C-bSNQwdL&dpSrc=sims&preST=_AC_UL160_SR119%2C160_&refRID=0X5482MGT748GF1T5AHH) and then [Schaum's Outline of Advanced Calculus](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Schaums-Outline-Advanced-Calculus-Third/dp/0071623663/ref=sr_1_4?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1451677051&sr=1-4&keywords=calculus+schaums). Both books have lots of worked examples and questions to try.

I would suggest [Calculus by Spivak](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Calculus-Michael-Spivak/dp/0521867444/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1451676906&sr=1-1&keywords=calculus), but it is more technical than you probably want to go.

Answer (score 0):

I think [The Calculus 7](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0673469131) by Louis Leithold would serve as a good textbook for your undergraduate computer science students.  I used this book in teaching students with the same major a few years back, and all of them found it to be detailed and challenging -- worthy to be read thoroughly.